# How do i declare an array as public in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, global

I have a function that involves declaring and populating an array called ArrayRoute. I need to reference this array later in a for loop. How do I set this array as global so I can access it outside of the function?

Thanks

```
function route(permutation, origins) {
    var myroute = origins[0];
    var ArrayRoute = [];
    ArrayRoute.push(origins[0]);
    console.log('ArrayRoute= ' + ArrayRoute);
    for (var i = 0; i < permutation.length; i++){
        myr += '\n' + myd[permutation[i] - 1];
        ArrayRoute.push(myd[permutation[i] - 1]);
    }
    return myroute;
}

for (i = 0; i < ArrayRoute.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(ArrayRoute[i] + '->' + ArrayRoute[i + 1]);
}

console.log('ArrayRouteeee= ' + ArrayRoute);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.
If you create the array inside the function then it is only accessible from within the function body.

You can declare it outside of the function:

```
let ArrayRoute = [];
function route(permutation, origins) {
    var myroute = origins[0];
    ArrayRoute.push(origins[0]);
    console.log('ArrayRoute= ' + ArrayRoute);
    for (var i = 0; i < permutation.length; i++){
        myr += '\n' + myd[permutation[i] - 1];
        ArrayRoute.push(myd[permutation[i] - 1]);
    }
    return myroute;
}

for (i = 0; i < ArrayRoute.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(ArrayRoute[i] + '->' + ArrayRoute[i + 1]);
}

console.log('ArrayRouteeee= ' + ArrayRoute);
```

You can pass it as a parameter to the function:

```
function route(permutation, origins, ArrayRoute) {
    ...
}
```

Or you can return the array as a result from the function:

```
function route(permutation, origins) {
    var myroute = origins[0];
    var ArrayRoute = [];
    ArrayRoute.push(origins[0]);
    console.log('ArrayRoute= ' + ArrayRoute);
    for (var i = 0; i < permutation.length; i++){
        myr += '\n' + myd[permutation[i] - 1];
        ArrayRoute.push(myd[permutation[i] - 1]);
    }
    return { myroute, ArrayRoute };
}

let { myroute, ArrayRoute } = route(...);
```